# pushViewController using UINavigationItem instead of UINavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, tableview, uinavigationitem, pushviewcontroller

I have implemented a method didSelectRowAtIndexPath that should push another view. I have a code running properly using a navigationController but in this case I am using a **navigationItem** on a view. How could I trigger a view? Thanx

Error log:

```
2010-03-25 00:09:52.459 TableArchive[1062:207] trigger
2010-03-25 00:09:52.461 TableArchive[1062:207] *** -[UINavigationItem pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3921ca0
2010-03-25 00:09:52.462 TableArchive[1062:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UINavigationItem pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3921ca0'
2010-03-25 00:09:52.463 TableArchive[1062:207] Stack: (


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSLog(@"trigger");

 if(dvController == nil) {
   DetailView *aController =[[DetailView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];

   self.dvController = aController;

   [aController release];
 }

 [[self navItem]pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

 [dvController release];
}
```

Comment: Dave DeLong is right. You can't use navigation item to push next view.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can't do `[[self navItem]pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];` because a `UINavigationItem` isn't a `UINavigationController`.

You have to use `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];` instead.  Beyond that, I don't get what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the UINavigationItem from the view (XIB ?) as your UINavigationController navigation item. You can do this by setting an IBOutlet to the navItem and at your code you just do self.navControllet.navItem = navItem (something like that).